# is that thread safe to update entry.value.field directly in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: concurrenthashmap

Sometimes, we need to update one `field` of `entry.value`. 
the thread safe way to do that is construct a new `entry.value` and
use `put` method to update. that is said, I need to make deep copy 
of original value even though I just do some little modification.

Can I do this update like

```
map[key].field = fieldValue;
```

Comment: What language are we in here?

Answer (score 1):

Hash map returns an entry safely, but assignment of a field is out of scope of the map. So, you should do something here for thread safety. Your code is equivalent to:

```
Entry entry = map[key];
entry.field = fieldValue;
```

Obviously the field assignment operator doesn't know anything about the map.

Comment: that is said, I need to extra `synchronized` or `volatile` to make sure the latest updated value can be seen by another thread?

Comment: @pythonee Yes, sure. But the point is - it is completely unrelated to the concurrent hash map.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a lock for the entry itself is needed. If it is just an assignment, then volatile.